# How to retrieve row with non-values if it has them otherwise null

Tags: sql

I have a table

```
key1 value1
key1 value2
key1 null
key2 null
key3 null
key3 value
```

In the end the table should look like this

```
key1 value1
key1 value2
key2 null
key3 value
```

The first thing that came to my mind is to group by key and take max of value, but with key1 it won't work. Another idea is to count rows with null values and all rows by key, then compare them and if they don't match then exclude null values. But I am wondering whether there is an easier solution

Comment: Any chance/risk there are duplicated rows?

Comment: @jarlh Yes, there are rows as
key2 null
key2 null. As for duplicate values within one key, not sure

Comment: Do you want all key2 null rows, or just one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your have a table `t` with columns `a` and `b`, you can do:

```
select x.a, t.b
from (select distinct a from t) x 
left join t on t.a = x.a and t.b is not null
```

Result:

```
a     b
----  ------
key1  value1
key1  value2
key3  value
key2  null
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jPpLYdEq).

Answer (score 0):

```
select d1.key, d2.value 
  from
(select distinct key from dummy) d1 
  left join (select * from dummy where value is not null) d2 
  on d1.key = d2.key;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/iqgYuiVB)

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (
            partition by key
            order by case when value is null then 1 else 2 end) as rn
    from T
)
select * from data
where rn = 1 or value is not null;
```

No joins or subqueries necessary. Just rank the null values and keep only the ones that come first. Some platforms let you specify null sort order so you might be able to remove the `case` expression and sort on the straight column value.